# Is there a way to access event bubbling tree?

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

I'm working on an app where I need to have an event listener for some containers that are cloned and have the same properties. On a click I would like to receive the container's id, so I can execute a function. For example, the html containers are as such:

```
<div id="myContainer" class="col">
        <p class="bullet-right">&#9673</p>
        <p class="bullet-left">&#9673</p>
        <a href="#" class="color-picker"><i class="fas fa-palette color-inpust"></i></a>
        <input class="box main-title center-align" type="text" value="Enter title here">
    </div>

<div id="myContainer2" class="col">
        <p class="bullet-right">&#9673</p>
        <p class="bullet-left">&#9673</p>
        <a href="#" class="color-picker"><i class="fas fa-palette color-inpust"></i></a>
        <input class="box main-title center-align" type="text" value="Enter title here">
    </div>
```

Only the id name is different. So when targeting a general event listener such as:

```
$(window).mousedown(function(e){
```

Or

```
$('body > div').mousedown(function(e){
```

I can use the e.target.id but if the click is on a class inside the container I need to use e.target.parentElement.id to track it down, and it becomes unflexible. Is there a neat way to access the bubbling tree and look specifically for the id name 'myContainer' for example?

Also, I tried to use $(window).get(0).addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
But the event.target.id always points to the exact clicked element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why wouldn't you (a) add a class to all of the `div`'s you are concerned about, and (b) bind the event listener to that class (eg `<div id="myContainer" class="my-click-target">`)? In that way, you'd capture any click events _inside_ or _on_ the div you are concerned with, and wouldn't have to track "bubbling tree"....

Comment: Thanks mate obviously you're right and it's a smiple solution I was just wondering if it's possible to achieve only with jQuery thanks a lot!